# disable scroll by 3 and 4 fingers on synaptics touchpad

Tags: manjaro, scrolling, synaptic, kde5

I am fine with scrolling with 2 fingers. I have already disbaled edge scrolling by 1 finger.
I want to disable click and scrolling by 3 and 4 fingers on my synaptics touchpad.

System details:

Operating System: Manjaro Linux
KDE Plasma Version: 5.15.3
KDE Frameworks Version: 5.56.0
Qt Version: 5.12.2
Kernel Version: 5.0.5-1-MANJARO
OS Type: 64-bit
Touchpad: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad

I am using libinputgestures (2.42-1) for gestures (but did not enable scrolling for 3 and 4 fingers in there), config file is:

```
gesture swipe up    4   xdotool key super+Page_Up
gesture swipe down  4   xdotool key super+Page_Down
gesture swipe right 4   xdotool key ctrl+alt+Right
gesture swipe left  4   xdotool key ctrl+alt+Left
gesture swipe right_up 4 xdotool key XF86AudioPlay
gesture swipe left  3   xdotool key alt+Right
gesture swipe right 3   xdotool key alt+Left
gesture swipe right_up 3 xdotool key ctrl+Tab
gesture swipe left_down 3 xdotool key ctrl+shift+Tab

#gesture pinch in   2   xdotool key ctrl+minus
#gesture pinch out  2   xdotool key ctrl+plus

gesture pinch anticlockwise 2 xdotool key XF86AudioLowerVolume
gesture pinch clockwise 2 xdotool key XF86AudioRaiseVolume

swipe_threshold 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by un-installing `xf86-input-synaptics` and installing `xf86-input-libinput`. Thanks to arch wiki! :-D